# When I run it says: null // RELATIONS 1 - 1

Tags: java

I am finishing up my program to generate a receipt 
My program reads three facts, lecturaAnterior, lecturaActual and stratum. 
After doing that tells me nulll

What could it be?

Thank you for your contributions.

CLASS ONE

```
public class Suscriptor {
    private int nuip;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;`




    public Suscriptor(int nuip, String nombre, String apellido) {
        this.nuip = nuip;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }

    public int getNuip() {
        return nuip;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }


}
```

CLASS TWO

```
public class Vivienda {
    private String direccion;
    private String barrio;
    private String ciudad;
    private byte estrato;`


    public Vivienda(String direccion, String barrio, String ciudad, byte estrato) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
        this.barrio = barrio;
        this.ciudad = ciudad;
        this.estrato = estrato;

    }

    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }

    public String getBarrio() {
        return barrio;
    }

    public String getCiudad() {
        return ciudad;
    }

    public byte getEstrato() {
        return estrato;
    }
```

CLASS THREE

```
public class Recibo {
    public long lecturaAnterior;
    public long lecturaActual;
    public Vivienda viviend;
    public Suscriptor suscrip;`




    public Recibo(long lecturaAnterior, long lecturaActual) 
    throws Exception {
        if (lecturaAnterior <= 0.0F ){
            Exception e = new Exception ("La lectura anterior no puede ser menor a cero");
            throw e;
        }
        this.lecturaAnterior = lecturaAnterior;
        this.lecturaActual = lecturaActual;
        this.viviend = viviend;
        this.suscrip = suscrip;

    }

    public long getLecturaAnterior() {
        return lecturaAnterior;
    }

    public long getLecturaActual() {
        return lecturaActual;
    }

    public Vivienda getViviend (){
        return viviend ;
    }

  public Suscriptor getSuscrip () {
      return suscrip ;
  }


public long Consumo (){
    return ( this.lecturaActual - this.lecturaAnterior );

}

public long cargoBasico (){

    if  ( this.viviend.getEstrato() == 1 || this.viviend.getEstrato() == 2) {return 2000 ;}

    if (this.viviend.getEstrato() == 3) { return 5000 ; }

    if (this.viviend.getEstrato() == 4 || this.viviend.getEstrato() == 5 ) { return 5000; }

    if (this.viviend.getEstrato() == 6 || this.viviend.getEstrato() == 7 ) { return 12000 ; }

    return 0;

}

public long ValorConsumo () {
    return ( this.Consumo() * 250 ) ;
}
```

MAIN

```
import java.util.Scanner;`
/**
 *
 * @author christian1
 */
public class Programa {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        try {

            Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

            System.out.println("INGRESE LA LECTURA ANTERIOR : ");
            long lecturaAnterior = scan.nextLong();

            System.out.println("INGRESE LA LECTURA ACTUAL : ");
            long lecturaActual = scan.nextLong();

            System.out.println("INGRESE EL ESTRATO: ");
            byte estrato = scan.nextByte();

            Vivienda V1 = new Vivienda ("Av Junin 65-97","Rep De Israel","Villa de las Palmas",estrato );
            Suscriptor S1 = new Suscriptor (1113587452,"Juan","Roman");
            Recibo R1 = new Recibo (lecturaAnterior,lecturaActual);

            System.out.println ("PAGUE PORFAVOR: SEÑOR ... " + S1.getNombre()+"QUE VIVE EN "+ V1.getDireccion() + R1.ValorTotal() + " A CONTINUACION DISCRIMINAMOS SU CONSUMO" + R1.ValorConsumo() + R1.Incremento() + R1.Descuento() + R1.ValorIva() + R1.ValorTotal());


        } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());  

}
}   }
```

Comment: Did you try to debug your program?

Comment: Error message? Edit it in.

Comment: Some programs say null when they see people running. Others keep quiet. They might reveal their secrets if you sit down, relax and pay attention to them. They might scream a lot of interesting things besides screaming null which may help you discover why they complain if you spray them with some de-bug (you can always run in a park or some place far away from your computer, then you won't hear the null cries of your code :)

Comment: nice one @helderdarocha

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "tells me null".  Exactly what gets printed?  If there's an error message, please show all of it.  By the way, I think what ZouZou is suggesting is that you should use a debugger to step through your program, and check the values of all the variables on each line.  Has your teacher taught you how to do that yet?

Comment: The program reads 3 database, I enter the following and appears "null" exactly. 
No, not even teach me to debug the program. @DavidWallace

Comment: This close reason is incorrect.  One respondent has correctly diagnosed the problem, from the information given.  It would be good if people understood the difference between "there is not enough information to diagnose the problem" and "I can't be bothered to diagnose the problem".

Comment: as suggested use the options setter ZouZou 
but still getting "null" @DavidWallace

Comment: OK, I'm wondering if you're getting some kind of exception thrown, but without a message.  What happens if you replace `System.out.println(e.getMessage());` with `e.printStackTrace();` ?

Answer (score 2):

As ZouZou suggested you could have find the problem if you debug. Or read the exception may be. 
In class `Recibo` you don't set the values for

```
Vivienda viviend 
Suscriptor suscrip
```

In the constructor you just assigning them to self. Create those and pass it to constructor as you do for `lecturaAnterior`, `lecturaActual` or use a setter.

Comment: Clearly the correct answer.